# flutter_bloc `prev` and `curr` states are not getting updated

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I've gone though some answers already, and doing the stuff that's mentioned overthere but nothing is working. I'm using `cubit/state` arhic. for my project. And here's the flow:

#### State class

```dart
@immutable
class SastaWalletBalanceState extends Equatable {
  static bool match(SastaWalletState a, SastaWalletState b) =>
      a.balance != b.balance;

  final num? data;
  final String? message;

  SastaWalletBalanceState({
    this.data,
    this.message,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        this.data,
        this.message,
      ];
}

@immutable
class SastaWalletBalanceDefault extends SastaWalletBalanceState {}

@immutable
class SastaWalletBalanceLoading extends SastaWalletBalanceState {
  SastaWalletBalanceLoading() : super();
}

@immutable
class SastaWalletBalanceSuccess extends SastaWalletBalanceState {
  SastaWalletBalanceSuccess({num? data}) : super(data: data);
}

@immutable
class SastaWalletBalanceFailed extends SastaWalletBalanceState {
  SastaWalletBalanceFailed({String? message}) : super(message: message);
}
```

#### Cubit function

```dart
Future<void> getBalance() async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      balance: SastaWalletBalanceLoading(),
    ));
    try {
      final data = await repo.getBalance();

      emit(state.copyWith(
        balance: SastaWalletBalanceSuccess(data: data),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        balance: SastaWalletBalanceFailed(message: e.toString()),
      ));
    }
  }
```

#### UI part

Here's the problem, the `MultiBlocListener`, all other `BlocListener` are working fine except the one using this state, although I'm getting data from cubit, and from API.

```dart
...rest of the code
return MultiBlocListener(
      listeners: [
        BlocListener<SastaWalletCubit, SastaWalletState>(
          listenWhen: STWalletInitSessionState.match,
          listener: (context, state) async {
            final otpAlreadySent =
                state.initSession is STWalletInitSessionFailed &&
                    state.initSession!.message!.contains('already sent');

            final message = state.initSession?.message?.split(': ').lastOrNull;

            if (otpAlreadySent) {
              buttonLabel = 'Cancel';
              stCubit.getBalance();
              stateProvider.setStWallet(true);
              SnackBars.e(context, message!);
            }

            if (state.initSession is STWalletInitSessionFailed &&
                !otpAlreadySent) {
              buttonLabel = 'Use';
              stateProvider.setStWallet(false);
              stateProvider.setPartialPayment(false);
              SnackBars.e(context, message!);
            }

            // If wallet session is already initiated it will contain a specific message
            // In this case, make the get_balance call
            else if (state.initSession is STWalletInitSessionSuccess &&
                state.initSession!.data!.message!
                    .contains('A session had already been started.')) {
              stCubit.getBalance();
              stateProvider.setStWallet(true);
            }

            // Initiate session first time or if session has expired
            else if (state.initSession is STWalletInitSessionSuccess ||
                otpAlreadySent) {
              final dsmState = DSMProvider.state(context);
              dsmState.setDurationOTP(context, duration: otpDuration!);
              dsmState.startOtpTimer();

              final validated = await showModalBottomSheet<bool?>(
                context: context,
                isDismissible: false,
                enableDrag: false,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                builder: (context) {
                  return const _OTPModal();
                },
              );

              // Incase of validation, make get_balance call
              if (validated != null && validated) {
                stCubit.getBalance();
                buttonLabel = 'Cancel';
                WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                  stateProvider.setStWallet(true);
                });
              } else {
                stateProvider.setStWallet(false);
                stateProvider.setPartialPayment(false);
              }
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<SastaWalletCubit, SastaWalletState>(
          listenWhen: STWalletValidateSessionState.match,
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state.validateSessionState is STWalletValidateSessionFailed) {
              buttonLabel = 'Use';
              stateProvider.setStWallet(false);
              stateProvider.setPartialPayment(false);
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<SastaWalletCubit, SastaWalletState>(
          listenWhen: SastaWalletBalanceState.match,
          listener: (context, state) {
            print('----- balance listener -----');
            print(state.balance);

            if (state.balance is SastaWalletBalanceSuccess) { <--- THIS IS NOT PRINTING
              print('--- balance success -----');
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  builder: (_) {
                    return ListenableProvider.value(
                      value: stateProvider,
                      builder: (context, child) {
                        return DSMBottomPriceWidgetAfterBooking(
                          walletBalanceCall: true,
                          order: order,
                          payNow: !stateProvider.isPartialPaymentViaWallet
                              ? PayNow.visible
                              : PayNow.hidden,
                          payNowCall: () {
                            final walletProvider = bookingCubit
                                .state.paymentProvider!.data!
                                .where((element) => element.code!.contains(
                                    DSMPaymentProviderMapping.stWallet))
                                .first;
                            final walletCode =
                                walletProvider.methods!.first.code;
                            stateProvider.setPaymentMethod(
                                walletProvider.methods!.first);
                            bookingCubit.paymentTransaction(
                              walletCode,
                              order.orderId,
                              promoCode: {},
                            );
                          },
                          isExpanded: true,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        )
      ],
  //// .... rest of the code
```

Comment: Please do let me know if you I need to provide anything extra

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with a `ChangeNotifier` that keeps on rebuilding the screen and hence the listener was not getting a chance to handle the success state.

Moral of story: Always check if your current screen is rebuilding without any reason or not.